# Load generator model from Gan

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network

I train à CycleGan and now I want to eval it.

At the end of the cycleGan training, I was able to find the following file : latest_net_G_A.pth

When I try to load the model and evaluate it I have some issues :

```
model = torch.load(PATH)
model.eval()

AttributeError: ‘collections.OrderedDict’ has no attribute ‘eval’
```

I also tried :

```
model = Generator()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()

AttributeError : ‘torch.C_.Generator’ object has no attribute ‘load_state_dict’
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `load_state_dict` from the `Generator` instance, but the generator doesn't have such a method. Maybe you mean to call `torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your training code and fit method? Seemingly you have no evaluate method or eval decorator which is why you are getting this error.